# Proving the function set as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, function-spaces

For $x\ge y$, is the set of functions that satisfy the $\operatorname{f}(x)\gt \operatorname{f}(y)$ condition a vector space?

How should we approach this question before applying vector space axioms or how can we apply vector space axioms to determine that the function set is a vector space or not?

Comment: Do you mean the set of decreasing functions on the reals?  Or are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is the set closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Every function that satisfy this condition.

Comment: Right, but "this condition" isn't clear.

Comment: In particular, if $y=x$ we have $x\ge y$ and so $f(x)=f(y)>f(x)$, which holds for *no* real-values $f$.

Comment: Write down the axioms for a vector space.  One after another, test whether the set of functions satisfies the axioms.

Comment: Thank you. Our goal is that looking for that this function set is closed under scalar  multiptication and providing the other vector space axioms.

Comment: @saulspatz How can i apply all the axioms to function set? How can i be convinced that the function set is complete?

Comment: @Randall x and y are supposed to be fixed.

Comment: For example, on axiom says that the sum of two elements of the space is again an element of the space.  If $f$ and $g$ are two functions that satisfy the defining condition of your set, does $f+g$ also satisfy that condition?  If not, the answer is "no".  If so then pass on to the next axiom.  I have no idea what you mean by "complete" in this context.

Comment: @saulspatz Meaning of "complete" is that; for examle i found n functions that satisfies this condition and applied the axioms to n functions and all functions are provided. But how can i make sure that i tested all functions that satisfies this condition?

Comment: You can't do it that way.  There are infinitely many functions that satisfy the condition.  You must do it more abstractly.

Comment: @saulspatz  Yes i know. So how?

Comment: I can't believe that $x$ and $y$ were meant to be fixed.  If so, check out @kimchilover's comment.

Comment: There isn't some kind of algorithm for doing proofs.  you have to decide whether you think it's true, and if you do, think about *why* it's true.  Then turn that reasoning into a formal argument.

Comment: or come up with a counterexample to prove it’s not true

Comment: Ok. Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

To start, remember that the space of functions (on $\mathbb{R}$ here) is a vector space (with addition and scalar multiplication working as you expect them to, 1 is the multiplicative identity, and f = 0 is the additive identity).
The set of functions you're dealing with here is then a subset of this vector space. All that is left for you to do is to verify whether this subset is indeed a vector space (i.e. contains the additive identity and is closed under addition and scaling).